# How to blend borders of multiple raster files so that it doesn't leave any discrepancies while mosaicing them together?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I am using landsat data to create an FCC over a large basin area. I combined the raster files to get the entire area of the basin as one raster. But as the images were taken on different days, they don't merge together as one but look as if multiple images have been put together. Is there any way to blend the individual images into a whole ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.